# What is wrong with this MySQL query? Returning random results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

**Schools**

```
# id
* max_students
...
```

**Dates**

```
# id
* school
```

**Students**

```
# id
* date_id
...
* over_limit
* canceled - DEFAULT NULL
* logged_out - DEFAULT NULL
```

When user register a student, I use query to count registered students, if number of students aren't higher or equal to max_students in his/her school. This result (0 or 1) later save to **over_limit** cell

I use this query to count

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(S.id) >= 
  (SELECT SC.max_students
  FROM schools SC 
  JOIN dates D ON D.school = SC.id
  WHERE D.id = S.date_id)
,1,0)
FROM students S
WHERE S.date_id = "number from PHP" AND S.logged_out IS NULL AND S.canceled IS NULL
```

But there is something bad, because sometimes student was marked as over_limit even, when date wasn't full, sometimes when date was full, student wasn't marked as over_limit.

So I decided to log these results. I save result of the query above, COUNT and max_students selected in new query. In 177 occurrences, 9 times query returned bad result.

Can you explain what is wrong in my query?

Thank you

Comment: Are you certain that you want the conditions `S.logged_out IS NULL AND S.canceled IS NULL`?  What happens if they change after the fact?

Comment: Yes, `logged_out` is INT, NULL by default, and when user log out the student from course (table dates), I change this to 0 if no alternate student is registred, or ID of student which is alternate. `canceled` is VARCHAR, NULL by default. When admin cancel registration of this student, I put there reason why he did it.

Comment: And users never log back in / "uncancel" their registration?  If so, this could be concurrency-related... are you using transactions?

Comment: I don't understand first question. But yes, I use transactions.